# Steroids: NavigationBarButton displayed then vanished

Tags: navigationbar, steroids, appgyver

I'm new to Steroids and I'm trying to display a modal view with a button in the native navigation bar (will use it later for a side drawer).

Note: The use of a modal view doesn't require to override potential existing back button on the left side.

My view and its content are displayed normally with a nice NavigationBarButton "Filtres". But once the view is fully loaded the navigation bar is reloaded and the navigation bar button disappears.

Any idea why this happens and how fix it?

Here is the controller code:

```
    angular
      .module('profile-list')
      .controller('IndexController', function($scope, supersonic) {

        var drawerButton = new supersonic.ui.NavigationBarButton({    
            title: "Filtres",
            onTap: function(){    
                supersonic.logger.debug("click");
            }    
        });

        var navigationBarOptions = {    
            buttons: {
                left: [drawerButton]
            }    
        };

        supersonic.ui.navigationBar.update(navigationBarOptions);

});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the navbar update like this:

```
supersonic.ui.views.current.whenVisible( function(){
    var drawerButton = new supersonic.ui.NavigationBarButton({    
        title: "Filtres",
        onTap: function(){    
            supersonic.logger.debug("click");
        }    
    });

    var navigationBarOptions = {    
        buttons: {
            left: [drawerButton]
        }    
    };

    supersonic.ui.navigationBar.update(navigationBarOptions);
});
```

Also, you can test the button on the right side instead in case the `overrideBackButton` is somehow setting itself to true.

Comment: I've already tried to display the button on the right side but it doesnt change the behavior: the button is displayed on load but disappears once the view is fully loaded. I'll try the whenVisible part, thanks for your time.

Comment: When wrapping in whenVisible() I dont even have the "flash" display anymore on load. Any other lead?

Comment: This is also being discussed here in case the answer presents itself: [Muut Appgyver Forum](https://muut.com/appgyver#!/steroids:add-button-to-navigation-ba)